# How could i express changes in this image in English?

Tags: expressions

[image]

Am i right in saying that it's both sides became circular?

Comment: The ends of the lower one are rounded.

Comment: The corners are filleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ends are **[rounded](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rounded)**.
(Adjective)

> 1 : made round : flowing rather than jagged or angular

Both ends were **[rounded off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rounded%20off)**.
(Verb)

> 1 : to trim or finish into curved or rounded form

Circular would be understood but is more for when the entire piece becomes a circle, for example if you started with a square and made it a circle.